# Can we use ondblclick attribute to do nothing in JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Can i use ondblclick attribute of `<h:form>` to prevent double click events? Like do nothing on double click sort off thing?

Comment: I improved your answer. Check it out. And what do you want to prevent? Not a lot of components have this event. And client-side the event ends up on the `form` so you might be to late. Please better explain what you want to achieve. And you can try what you propose. Way more simple than asking

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean and the only full proof ways to prevent double submit that I know of are as follows.

1. Use [Deltaspike JSF Module](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#Double-SubmitPrevention) to prevent double submit.

> To avoid that the same content of a form gets submitted and therefore
>   processed multiple times, it is possible to use the tag
>   . As usual for DeltaSpike JSF-tags, the ds
>   namespace is http://deltaspike.apache.org/jsf. Just add this tag
>   within every JSF form-tag, you would like to safeguard.

2. Use [PrimeFaces Ajax Status](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml) with a modal dialog which blocks all clicking until the ajax response is complete.